# addEventListener("change" ... for input works changing innerHTML going up in value but not lower

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div block with a value I want to adjust as I change the value of the input. It works fine as the value of the input goes up, but going back down it doesn't change. Perhaps I'm overlooking something silly in my logic.

```js
var quanityAmount = document.getElementById("quantity");
var letterDisplay = document.getElementById("display");
quanityAmount.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var quanityValue = quanityAmount.value;
  if (quanityValue === 1) {
    letterDisplay.innerHTML = "a";
  } else if (quanityValue >= 2) {
    letterDisplay.innerHTML = "b";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" >

<div id="display">a</div>
```

I had a `console.log(quanityvalue)` and the value does change and detect such as 1, 2 and back to 1.

Comment: `quanityValue === 1` can never be true

Comment: Note that <input [number]> exposes a `valueAsNumber` getter.

Comment: @Kaiido I'm coming from a c++ background, I never actually thought to look deeper into details. Thank you for this insight.

Answer (score 1):

The input's value is a string so `"1" !== 1`. It needs to be converted to a number.

```js
var quanityAmount = document.getElementById("quantity");
var letterDisplay = document.getElementById("display");
quanityAmount.addEventListener("change", function() {
  var quanityValue = +quanityAmount.value;
  if (quanityValue === 1) {
    letterDisplay.innerHTML = "a";
  } else if (quanityValue >= 2) {
    letterDisplay.innerHTML = "b";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" >

<div id="display">a</div>
```

Comment: Interesting how that works, adding the `+` changes it to a number automatically? (javascript magic?)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/convert-a-string-to-an-integer